# does not allow null values - even if I specify null=True in models

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I don't understand: in my django-cms hook-app I want to give the opportunity to upload an image, but I do not that to be compulsory.

in models.py

```
   image1 = FilerImageField(related_name="image1", null=True, blank=True)
```

in my html template

```
  % if instance.image1 and instance.pic_label1 %}

    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" href="{% thumbnail instance.image1 680x453 crop='smart' %}" title="{{ instance.pic_label1 }}"><img src="{% thumbnail instance.image1 148x222  crop='smart' %}" class="images_events"/ ></a>
        <p>{{ instance.pic_label1 }}</p>

 {% endif %}
```

but when I run everything this error occurs:

```
 Cannot assign None: "ImageText.image1" does not allow null values.
```

Comment: did you add `null=True, blank=True` after you ran syncdb ?

Comment: yep , I drop that table (even if wasn't necessary I guess) and sync db then test

Comment: Yeah.. that is the problem. syncdb does not do alter table for you. You have to you something like django-south to manage the migrations for you

Comment: But I dropped table....shouldn't be enough? what shall I do?

Comment: Yeah. That is one way of doing it. But the right way of handling changes to models is through django-south

Comment: ok I ll try with django south then , weird cos dropping the table d be enough..

Comment: Afaik (but may be wrong) `null=True` on a `File/ImageField` doesn't do anything, so just `blank=True` should be enough. Plus it should allow you to have that field available always, empty or not. Less pain, less hassle, less migrations, more joy

Comment: clever one ! Thanks @SamueleMattiuzzo